# django-paypal recurring_payment_id is empty

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I am using [django-paypal](https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal) into my django application. I am trying to create recurring payment as:

```
paypal_dict = {
    "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
    "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
    "item_name": self.subscription.name,
    "a3": str(self.subscription.rate),
    "p3": 1,
    "t3": self.subscription.recuring_type,
    "src": "1",
    "sra": "1",
    "no_note": "1",
    "invoice": "%s" % str(self.order.pk),
    "notify_url": "my_notify_url",
    "return_url": "my_success_url",
    "cancel_return": "my_cancel_url",
    "currency_code": self.subscription.currency.code,
}

paypal_form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="subscribe")
```

I received only two ipn's which is `subscr_signup` and `subscr_payment` which is ok.
I received `payment_was_successful` which is good.
The problem is that `ipn_obj` never had value for `recurring_payment_id` and `payment_status`, both are empty always and in sandbox i can see that recurring profile is created. Am i making recurring payment wrong, am i missing some variable which will identify this as recurring payment?

Answer (score 2):

When you receive a "txn_type" variable with a "subscr_signup" value you don't receive a "recurring_payment_id" variable. You should get a "subscr_id" variable with the Recurring Profile ID you're looking for.

With Payments Standard Subscriptions the value should start like this "S-"

There are two types of Recurring Payment variables for IPN posts. It's kinda confusing - sorry.

Comment: Yes i am getting `subscr_id`. But this is not what i want. Because i need the `recurring_payment_id` to check at times the `payment_status`. How can i update the above request to send me the `recurring_payment_id` and `profile_status`??

Comment: When I create a Subscription button straight from the account it creates IPN posts with "recurring_payment" values returned. Custom buttons are given the "subscr_" values. I can't find the specific variable and value combination missing between the two
If you used Express Checkout, Automatic Billing, or Installment Plans the IPN posts created "recurring_payment" values.